# Cannot update Parse object via REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform

Right, so I'm simply trying to update my object via the REST API. My request succeeds, I get a 200 response back containing the latest updated timestamp, but the object's column value has not changed.

My `Movies` class has a `title` and a `genre` column, the rights on the class are set to public read write on all rows.

Here is some code

```
var data = {title:'The Revenant'};

qwest.put('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Movies/myObjectId', JSON.stringify(data))
    .then(function(xhr, response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(xhr, response, e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

The response I get back?

`{"updatedAt":"2016-01-24T07:59:54.977Z"}`

So the request succeeded but if I `GET` the object again or check in the Parse admin page, the object has not changed. What gives?

**EDIT**

FYI, if I use the Javascript SDK, I can update the model.

```
var Movies = Parse.Object.extend("Movies");
var query = new Parse.Query(Movies);

query.get(myObjectId, {
    success: function (movie) {
        movie.set("title", data.title);
        movie.save();
    },
    error: function (object, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

This updates the model. For my particular use case though, I would really prefer to use the REST API rather than the SDK, but I guess this means it is not a permissions issue or an id mismatch etc.,

Comment: var data = {"title":"The Revenant"};  try it out.. may work better

Comment: This gives a `400` response due to invalid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

code snippet

```
qwest.put('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Movies/Dh7zjiP9KW', data,    {dataType:"json",headers:{'x-parse-application-id':'XXX','X-Parse-REST-    API-Key':'XXX'}})
            .then(function(xhr, response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function(xhr, response, e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! Setting the data type explicitly was the necessary step.

Answer (score 0):

The response you're getting indicates that the object was updated successfully.  Double check that you're looking at the correct object, and that the "updatedAt" field matches the response you saw earlier.

What happens if you fetch the object right away, using the same "qwest" client and `https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Movies/myObjectId` resource URL (with the correct object id)?

Comment: Yep, object is correct. If I perform a `get` request inside of the `then` promise the correct object comes back. Its timestamp has been updated but its title remains the same.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the client you're using? Which headers are you setting when making this request?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing JSON.stringify(data) and just pass data,

Comment: Below code works for me, I set the datatype to json.

Comment: Hmm I'll try explicitly setting the data type and report back